# Showing only filename and file size windows dos

Tags: windows, dir

This may sound easy to you all, I'm just trying to list the list of the files in a directory and their size only.  I tried bunch of options dir / help, but don't seem to be able to get it right. Can you help please? I also looked around but all I find are reference to diretory
size.

```
       I want the out put to look like this

       a.txt  21
       b.txt  72
       3.txt  73
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for %F in (*) do @echo %F     %~zF
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch file.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*) do echo %%F     %%~zF
```

---

For fixed width, it probably is better to list the size first, since that width does not vary so much. Twelve digits is almost enough for 1 terabyte. File name length can vary a lot.

Here is a batch script listing size in bytes (up to 12 digits), followed by file name:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (*) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "size=            %%~ZF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !size:~-12! !name!
  endlocal
)
```

The toggling of delayed expansion is to prevent corruption of the file name if it contains the `!` character. Any FOR variable value is corrupted if delayed expansion is enabled and the value contains `!`.

Comment: Hi  Thanks I see that this works .. Is there any way to fix the spacing so that the file-name & file size fall neatly under one column?

Comment: how do you get this to dump into a .txt file, where does the > file.txt go?

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts - Put parentheses around the entire command, and then put the redirection afterwards. `(for ... do ...) >output.txt`. That way the file is created only once with all output. Without the parentheses the file is recreated each iteration, so only the last iterated line would be captured. You could use `>>output.txt`  without parentheses to capture everything, but then old content that existed prior to running the command would be preserved, and the output capture is slower.

Comment: A little contribution /R parameter will help listing also files under subdirectories


    for /R %F in (*.pdf) do @echo %F     %~zF>>output.txt

will list all pdf files under all subdirectories